# Turn trained TensorFlow model into fixed operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to take a trained TensorFlow model and convert all the `tf.Variables` and their respective weights (either from within a running `tf.Session` or from a checkpoint) into `tf.constants` with that value, such that one can run the model on a new input tensor without initializing or restoring the weights in a session? So can I basically condense a trained model into a fixed and immutable TensorFlow operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a `freeze_graph.py` tool just for that purpose.

It is described (a bit) in the [Tool Developer's Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#freezing). And you can find usage example in the [Preparing models for mobile deployment](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models) section.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!